# Starting out fresh and then becoming a senior

Tags: riddle, wordplay

I started out fresh dude, then I became more soft. But then something happened and I ended up being a senior. What was I before my seniority?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible answer is that you were a

> junior

Before you were a senior. This references

> High school/college years

Where

> A "fresh dude" is a freshman (first year), becoming "more soft" (thanks @OP for the "more") references a sophomore (second year), and "senior" is the fourth year. Junior, then, fits in as the third year.